# generating gridview rows based on a data table value

Tags: c#, .net, list, datatable

I'm currently working on a control which will allow me to assign sizes to placeholders on a page. The control working using various data tables and so is getting quite complex.

I want to make the process of creating a layout as automated as possible.

What I am trying to do is generate a number of gridview rows based on a value being pulled from a datatable.

Here is my code so far

```
List<GridData> Grids = new List<GridData>();
        Grids.Add(new GridData { Size = 1, Title = "Grid_1" });
        Grids.Add(new GridData { Size = 2, Title = "Grid_2" });
        Grids.Add(new GridData { Size = 3, Title = "Grid_3" });
        Grids.Add(new GridData { Size = 4, Title = "Grid_4" });
        Grids.Add(new GridData { Size = 5, Title = "Grid_5" });
        Grids.Add(new GridData { Size = 6, Title = "Grid_6" });
        Grids.Add(new GridData { Size = 7, Title = "Grid_7" });
        Grids.Add(new GridData { Size = 8, Title = "Grid_8" });
        Grids.Add(new GridData { Size = 9, Title = "Grid_9" });
        Grids.Add(new GridData { Size = 10, Title = "Grid_10" });
        Grids.Add(new GridData { Size = 11, Title = "Grid_11" });
        Grids.Add(new GridData { Size = 12, Title = "Grid_12" });

        GV_PlaceHolders.DataSource = from x in db.DT_Layouts2s
                                     where x.LayoutID == int.Parse(DDL_Layouts.SelectedValue.ToString())
                                     select new
                                         {
                                             x.LayoutID,
                                             x.PlaceHolders,
                                             Grids,
                                         };

        GV_PlaceHolders.DataBind();
```

Now the way I want to generate the rows is by calling upon the place holders int value but I have no idea where even start with generating dynamic rows based on a value.

Can anyone point me in the right direction???

Cheers